# "Find" in the e-mail shown in the reading pane in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there a way to search in the content of the e-mail shown *in the reading pane* of Outlook? If yes, is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

I know that I can open the e-mail in a separate window and then search with F4, but this doesn't seem to work in the preview pane.

Comment: It sucks that Outlook doesn't have such a basic feature implemented in the preview pane. But, thanks to you I learned about the F4 trick for any email opened in its own window.

Answer (score 5):

Use keyboard shortcut:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.
This brings up the **Find and Replace** window, with the **Goto** tab active. Click on the **Find** tab. Voila, now search within your Outlook Preview/Reading pane!

Comment: That's it. 
After these many years... They haven't provided a button to show this dialogue in the preview pane...

Answer (score 1):

I have found a better way then I could find elsewhere.
This is for finding text in an email currently being previewed in the preview pane.
Make a macro that opens the email and then brings up the find text dialog.

```
Sub FindText()
  SendKeys "^o{F4}"
End Sub
```

Then assign this macro to the ribbon wherever you find it most helpful.
I add it to the quick access toolbar and in its own group on the home tab.
Sadly, I have found no way to make this fire with a keyboard shorcut.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's not an easy native way to search in the preview pane.  You can use Outlook's advanced find (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) but that will search all messages, not just the current one.

You could probably program a macro to do that, but it would be a hassle.  Programming for Outlook is different than programming for other Office applications.

Answer (score 0):

Type your search term into Search box.

Press Enter.

The search term shows in Search box; List of messages only shows the messages containing the search term. All occurrences of the search term in the message currently showing in Preview pane are highlighted.

Click in the Preview pane.

Pressing Shift-F4 repeatedly now works as Find Next: all occurrences of the search term will "double-highlight" one after the other.